# DataGridTemplateColumn row hover textbox foreground

Tags: wpf, xaml, styling, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a DataGridTemplateColumn with a textbox inside of it. When I hover on the row, all other Foregrounds turn white except the textbox. What kind of styling can I apply to the textbox to make it's foreground change to match the other textblocks/fonts when the mouse is hovering over the row?

Example XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="Test 123" />
    <TextBlock Text="Test 123" />
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Styling

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{StaticResource BlackBrush}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{StaticResource BlackBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="5, 10" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an additional `Style` for the `TextBox`:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```